# Validation after submit not working?

Tags: php, validation, submit

i have some validation written out in PHP and i only want the fields to be validated if the submit button is hit so i added the:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

line around my code but now it doesn't seem to be validating at all, before i added the line it validated just fine but it validated as soon as the form was opened which is not what i want, instead i want it to validate once the submit button is pressed. Here is my code (i am fairly new to PHP so it probably look great) :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $post = $_POST["post"];
    $msgp = "";

    if (empty($post)) {
        $msgp = '<span class="error"> Please enter postcode</span>';
    }
    if (!empty($post)) {
        if(!is_numeric($post)) {
            $msgp = '<span class="error"> Data entered was not numeric</span>';
        } else if(strlen($post) != 4) {
            $msgp = '<span class="error"> Postcode must be 4 digits in length</span>';
        } else {
            $msgp = '<span class="error> Please enter a postcode</span>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the field itself:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi">
    <input type="text" id="post" name="post"><?php echo $msgp; ?></td>
</form>
```

Any help on fixing my errors would be appreciated, i have been staring at this for a while.

Comment: you are missing the submit button there won't be any `isset($_POST['submit'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add another input field to the form like this...

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="dowhatever.php" id="eoi">
     <input type="text" id="post" name="post" value="<?php if(!empty($msgp)) { echo $msgp; } ?>" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

You checking the variable `$_POST["sumbit"]` to see if it was set but you didn't have a field in the form with the name 'submit' so your script would never pass the check because `$_POST["submit"]` would never be set.